# PreAuthorize only works on GET requests

Tags: java, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot project utilizing mutual TLS. Everything works fine for any GET endpoints, but my POST endpoints return the following:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-03-26T11:28:38.778+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/audit/joe"
}
```

I assume I'm doing something subtly wrong, but I'm not seeing it.

The following is my configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class X509AuthenticationServer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(X509AuthenticationServer.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .x509()
                    .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService()
    {
        return new UserDetailsService()
        {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
            {
                System.out.println("userDetailsService::loadUserByUsername() :: Username: " + username);

                if (username.equalsIgnoreCase("allowed-user"))
                {
                    return new User(username, "", AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
                } else
                {
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s not found", username));
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And the following is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class AuditController
{
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/audit/{username}", method = RequestMethod.POST), consumes = "application/json")
    public void audit(@PathVariable("username") final String username,
                      @RequestBody final AuditRequest auditRequest,
                      final HttpServletResponse response) throws JsonProcessingException
    {
        // Business logic

        response.setStatus(201);
    }
}
```

This controller's GET method works as expected:

```
@Controller
public class UserController
{
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String user(final Model model, final Principal principal)
    {
        final UserDetails currentUser = (UserDetails) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();

        model.addAttribute("username", currentUser.getUsername());

        return "user";
    }
}
```

And here are my dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Do you have `@PreAuthorize` annotation on the get method? If so what is it? What is the spring-security version?

Comment: I assume your `GET` endpoints also annotated with `@PreAuthorize`. Are you sure Spring Security is enforcing access control on them?  Being authorized and failure to check authorization both give the same results (speaking from personal experience).

Comment: @Paul not in my experience. Unauthorized = 401, failing the role check will result in a 403, like is the case here.

Comment: @Gimby sorry, I was not clear. When I wrote "failure to check authorization" I meant that if Spring Security is incorrectly configured and thus not protecting an endpoint (or service method in the case of the application I work on) then a user will be able to access the endpoint. I did not mean "failure to pass authorization".

Comment: @paul spring security by default protects everything as soon as you put it in a project, you need to specifically configure endpoints to have no protection. The manual security config in the question does this too. Whatever experience you have seem to stem from old spring security versions.